# jquery append new div

Tags: jquery, append, appendto

I want do hover in a div, append a new div in body part, some code here.

but my problem is: now it is not append a new div but replace the first all html. Where is the problem? Thanks.  http://jsfiddle.net/U7QqB/3/

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').hover(function(){
    var html = $(this).find('.text').html();   
    $('body').append('<div id="object"/>').html(html).css({'top':'200px','left':'300px','z-index':'10'});
  });
});
```

css

```
.click{position:realavite;top:100px;left:300px;}
.text{display:none;}
.object{position:absolute;}
```

html

```
<body>
<h1>A hover append div text</h1>
<div class="click">
    <img src="http://nt3.ggpht.com/news/tbn/U7Q-7enFr00rUM/1.jpg" />
    <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) returns the *original* jQuery object (the one containing the `<body>` element), not a new one containing the appended content.

You can use [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead:

```
$('<div id="object">').appendTo('body').html(html).css({
    'top': '200px',
    'left': '300px',
    'z-index': '10'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div/>',{
  id: 'object'
}).appendTo('body')
  .html(html)
  .css({
     'top': '200px',
     'left': '300px',
     'z-index': '10'
});
```